# Typescript syntax: What the heck is this?

Tags: typescript

I'm a JS guy looking at an object in Typescript (it's being used in my work project) and I've stumbled into this syntax:

```
myClassFunction: () => void = () => {
    // my function internals here
}
```

I'm... honestly not sure what to make of this. What is this syntax, what does it do, what does it mean, and what is it called? (To my eyes, it looks as though we're assigning an anonymous function to another anonymous function, which shouldn't happen, but void is a TS type, so.....I'm stumped.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to that:

## a type annotation:

`: () => void`

This means its a function that takes nothing and returns nothing

## fat arrow function

```
() => {
    // my function internals here
}
```

This is an ES6 fat arrow function. More on these here : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

## Opinion

Personally I wouldn't annotate this.

```
var myClassFunction = () => {
    // my function internals here
}
```

And just let typescript infer the type:

[image]

Comment: I understand ES6. I didn't understand the type declaration. I'd expect something more like this: `myFunction: (): void => { //blah }`. That's what I've seen throughout Typescript - I'm not sure why you would need to specify that a function doesn't take any arguments, due to the way that JS handles arguments...

Comment: See my opinion section

Comment: Know what I just realized? That syntax threw me for a loop. I would expect a class method not to have a colon before the parens, which made it look like an object function (as I'm used to seeing in JS). For better or for worse, it looks like TS allows you to declare types using variable syntax. Knowing this, this should be: `myFunction(): void { //blah }`.

Comment: Using arrows for a class function can be useful if you plan to pass those functions around disconnected from the class instance. (more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA)

Comment: Maybe I'd have to look at the javascript, but functions in JS are first-class objects, so I'd imagine that you'd be able to pass them around anyway? It should compile down to prototype methods. What's even more confusing is that in ES6, lambda syntax changes the `this` scope - I think Typescript emulates this with `that = this` in the JS - so I'm not sure how well that would work, really. I guess I'll have to watch that video. I can't see myself using TS outside of my work environment (because that's what they've chosen) so I don't imagine I'll run into this much.

Comment: As to your opinion - I agree. I think that the strengths of Typescript do come with inferred types when they're usable. Unfortunately, my team of .NET-centric guys (who dislike JS) have decided to use annotations and interfaces everywhere. It helps with Intellisense in Visual Studio, but not much else, I'm afraid.